# ADB command to dial Code *#06#

Tags: adb

I am wondering if there is any way to run *# codes on android using adb command

I have tried this:

```
**service call phone 2 s16 "*#06#"**
```

tried with % instead of # as well.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: would this work? http://www.digitalinternals.com/mobile/android-adb-shell-dial-number-trick/382/

Comment: Thankyou Madushan, I tried this already, it does work however the code doesnt run, It goes back to normal dialing screen,

Answer (score 3):

Here's the command to type in ADB mode to show IMEI info:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.deviceinfo.ImeiInformation
```

For Terminal Emulator from device:

```
am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.deviceinfo.ImeiInformation
```

Comment: but i still need to know how I can run that command from adb, as i want to run another code for testing phone, which is  *#0*#

Comment: Try: `am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.TestingSettings`

Comment: gives me this error, adb shell
ell am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.TestingSettings     <
tent { cmp=com.android.se/system/bin/sh: adb: not found
ttings/.TestingSettings }
arting: Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.TestingSettings }                  <
/system/bin/sh: Starting:: not found
0) requires com.sec.testingsettings.permission.KEYSTRING                      <
droid.os.P/system/bin/sh: syntax error: '(' unexpected
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)                      <el.java:16

Comment: Download [Activity Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher). Select Settings app in that app and note down which Activity corresponds to the Testing Activity and launch it using `am start`

Comment: sorry i didnt understand, Can you explain a bit more please. I have downloaded the app "Activity Laucher" but dont understand what to do next. Many thanks